Sending meta WhatsApp flows as the first message problem
In meta WhatsApp flows, is it possible to send flow message as the first message instead of a template message? I know there is a option to build flows within template messages like marketing template or utility template, but the problem in that inbuild template flows is that we cannot integrate flows endpoints.
But we can do all sorts of thing in flow builder, we can integrate it with endpoint but the problem with that is that we cannot send the flow as the first message. Is there a solution for it?
I tried using flows from template builder directly but that doesn't include flow endpoints. So I need a way to send flows messages as a first message in which flow is integrated with flow endpoints.

You can't create a Flow with an endpoint from the template builder interface. However, you can create a flow with endpoint first, then create a new message template and link it to the existing flow with endpoint using the API. Check the docs here
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/flows/gettingstarted/sendingaflow#templatemessages

Thank you so much . It worked . You don't know but you have solved a big problem . And I should have read the documentation well I think . Its my bad .
